# How to export comments from katalon to external file

Tags: katalon-studio

I m new to Katalon.
I m trying to document the usage of the test automation I am working on.
The intention here is to maintain a document which contains all the Objects I have defined and Keywords being called in the test cases.

My test case is completely Keyword driven, so each keyword precisely doing an individual verification of the module we are trying to test automate.

My thought here is if we can export the comments provided for each Keyword to an external document, it will ease my job to document the complete functionality of my test automation.

And the exported file will become the help doc for any new developer to understand the existing pieces and enhance.

Comment: I think I can write a script to extract all the comments from Keyword files, but just wanted to check if we have any facility which is already there in the studio.

Comment: I don't think Katalon has an option to do that.